# how do I convert linq to lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How do I convert this LINQ query to lambda?

```
var res = from c in db.Client
                          where db.TimesheetLine.Select(o => o.ClientId).Contains(c.Id)
                          select c;
```

This resultant should be on a dropdown list so I started like this:

```
ViewBag.ClientId = new SelectList(db.Client, "Id", "ClientName");
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need lambda? Why you cant use `res` variable for `SelectList`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hope this answers your question. Let me know if it does/doesn't work:

```
var res = db.Client.Where(x => db.TimesheetLine.Select(o => o.ClientId).Contains(x.Id));
```